# In Mark 4:40, what is the accurate translation of "οὕτω"?

Tags: greek, mark

When I was looking Mark 4:40 I was little confused for the word "οὕτω" translation and meaning. For it was translated in many English translations as "so", "So" in English may means:

- Thus, like this.
- So much, very, too, greatly.

The word "οὕτω" in Greek has the two meanings also, i.e: thus and so much. Beside other meanings not required here.

Mark 4:40;

> 40. καὶ εἶπεν αὐτοῖς· τί δειλοί ἐστε **οὕτω**; πῶς οὐκ ἔχετε πίστιν;
>       And he said unto them, Why are ye **so** fearful? how is it that ye have no faith? KJV.

Some English translations don't mention "so". All Arabic translations I had read have the translation "هكذا" which means the English "thus","like this".

So, what is the accurate translation of "οὕτω" in the phrase of Mark 4:40?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can understand *so* here in the King James Bible (in 17th century English) to be synonymous with *thus* - i.e. *in this manner*.<sup>*</sup>  It is not, I believe, an expression of extreme degree (e.g. "so hot" or "so cold").  I think modern translations that see it this way miss the mark.  Take for an extreme example the ISV:  *Why are you such cowards?*

A very literal version - the *Orthodox New Testament* - translates the verse:

> *Why are ye cowardly in this manner?*

More modern translation have retained the choice of *so* as well as its place in the English word order, which strikes a modern reader as  implying "so much" and not "thus", as you indicate.  The confusion here is not in the Greek but in the English, I think.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sup>See, e.g., The *Complete Oxford English Dictionary* (1971 ed.), p.344ff.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

‘So’ according to the footnote in NET version is quite clear. It is the greek translation ‘kai’ that agrees to the previous narrative.